# Load Image Source from Html instead of Css

Tags: html, css, image, focus

I have been using some code for a thumbnail carousel using Focus, I am just wondering if it is possible to mimic the functionality of the carousel but change that the image is loaded within the html instead of having to have the images url in the css. Is it possible to do when using focus?

Html:

```
<button class="mdT mdI1" ></button>
<button class="mdT mdI2" ></button>
<button class="mdT mdI3" ></button>
<button class="mdT mdI4" ></button>
```

Css:

```
.mdT {
        width:96px;
        height:96px;
        border:0px;
        outline:0;
        vertical-align:middle;
        background-color:#AAAAAA;
    }
    .mdT:focus {
        width:256px;
        height:256px;
    }

/* Change Images Depending On Focus */
    .mdI1       {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/96x96/AAAAAA&text=img1');     }
    .mdI1:focus {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/256x256/555555&text=Image+1');   }
    .mdI2       {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/96x96/AAAAAA&text=img2');     }
    .mdI2:focus {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/256x256/555555&text=Image+2');   }
    .mdI3       {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/96x96/AAAAAA&text=img3');     }
    .mdI3:focus {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/256x256/555555&text=Image+3');   }
    .mdI4       {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/96x96/AAAAAA&text=img4');     }
    .mdI4:focus {   background-image:url('http://placehold.it/256x256/555555&text=Image+4');   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1h68hs7n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like this `<div style="background-image: url(...)"></div>`

When it comes to `:focus`, no, but using `mouseover` could be an option.

---

Update

If it is possible to add an inner element, you could do like this

```css
.mdT {
  position: relative;
  width:96px;
  height:96px;
  border:0px;
  outline:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#AAAAAA;
}
.mdT:focus {
  width:256px;
  height:256px;
}
.mdT span  {
  display: none;
}
.mdT:focus span  {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="mdT" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/96x96/AAAAAA&text=img1">
  <span style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/256x256/555555&text=Image+1"></span>
</button>

<button class="mdT" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/96x96/AAAAAA&text=img2">
  <span style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/256x256/555555&text=Image+2"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand how it would scale the image by doing the <div style="background-image: url(...)"></div>?

Comment: @Bethfiander How do you set the focus?

Comment: @Bethfiander Also, is it possible adding an inner element?

Comment: Sorry would you be able to show me an example on jsfiddle of what you mean?

Comment: @Bethfiander Updated my answer with a possible solution using `:focus`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks alot for your time and help!

Comment: @Bethfiander Glad to help :)